# Wordpress mod_rewrite rule. Stop redirecting from example.com to www.example.com

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to add a rule to my .htaccess file. This mod_rewrite needs to prevent my site from going to www.example.com, but rather stay on the example.com URL.

Please help.

UPDATE::

Here is my code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.za/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# uploaded ?les
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)??les/(.+) wp-includes/ms-?les.php??le=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is my first time working with the .htaccess file

Comment: If you log in to your Wordpress Backend, what is configured as Site Adress under "Settings"->"General"? If it says www.yoursite.co.za, just remove the "www."-Part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below rule in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Don't forget to change "example" in your own domain name.

Comment: Thank you for your help but, This gives an Internat Server Error

Comment: @Corrie - have you change `example.com` with your domain name ?

Comment: @Corrie: Does your Webserver have mod_rewrite installed? How did you create the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes it does have mod_rewrite installed. It is the Wordpress .htaccess file

Comment: I managed to remove the Error, but it still redirects to the www.mysite.co.za

Comment: No luck, still redirects to www.

Comment: So where you want to get it redirect ? You need to remove `www` ?

Comment: Yes want it to not go to www. but only mysite.com. This is for an plugin that doesn't accept the www